# IE Detection evaluating true for Chrome / FF?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser-detection

This should be straight forward but I'm having issues with this. I'm working on a site in an html5 boilerplate setup. Everything's good but IE(10) is having the usual margin issues. It's not catastrophic but it's causing a scrollbar to apply to the content area because it's taking up more vertical space on IE. I'm trying to extend the needed elements vertically using IE detection like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iestyle.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

iestyle.css contains:

```
#page-container { height: 1100px; }
#content { height: 835px ; }
#menu-footer { height: 560px; }
```

Normally I wouldn't specify exact heights this way and let them fill in naturally but I'm using a JQ plugin that's not letting me use that option. This should work though, it's simple enough but for whatever reason Chrome and FF are still applying the iestyle.css formatting. I even tried adding a class to the html object and then using that class as a hook in the style.css:

```
 .ieExtend #page-container { height: 1100px; }
```

The ieExtend class was still getting applied in Chrome and FF, so I'm assuming there's some issue with the detection itself...Any ideas?

Thnx.

Comment: Does Firefox actually download the `iestyle.css` file?  If you press F12, then select the "CSS" tab, do you see it listed in the source files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your conditional comment is going to work for IE10, as v10 removed support for conditional comments (http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/). So if the styles are applying in IE10, Chrome, *and* FF then that suggests that either you're using some other mechanism for detection that circumvents the conditional comment (which should ignore the stylesheet for all of those browsers) or you have duplicated the style rules inside style.css somehow. I suggest searching your code, perhaps doing a find for the value(s) to look for rogue rules, if you can't see another mechanism that might be applying them inadvertently (eg. through JS).

Comment: Ah, thanks Skrivener! I was actually unaware IE10 dropped conditional comments. The link you provided gave me some options and it's workin just fine now.